# Port Number, Creating Web Applications In SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

Does anyone know of Microsoft best practices for port numbering when creating seperate web applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are none, you can use port numbers or host headers as you please

Comment: i would disagree over here if you create a 2 digit port and try to open the site in firefox. you would not be able to open the site

Comment: never experienced that, we use ports such as 90 all the time with FF and Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest avoid using port number less than 1023 exception port 80 (for local host) you can find the details about TCP and UDP ports [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)